# Java Program issue with 24 hour time reset based logic and variables

Tags: java, variables, command-line, java-time

I'm creating a basic java program that is a Wordle clone in the command line. My main issue is with teh lgoci of being able to allow the player a max of 10 games played per day with a 24 horus reset. For some reason with my current code it doesn't see the maxGamesPlayed with the gamesPlayedToday variables, making it only let me play 1 game instead of 10. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

The main Commandle class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.*;

public class Commandle {
    public static final int MAX_TRIES = 6;
    public static final int MAX_DAILY_GAMES = 10;
    public static final Duration DAY_DURATION = Duration.ofDays(1); // 24 hours duration
    private static final String TIMESTAMP_FILE = "lastGameTimestamp.txt";

    private static int gamesPlayedToday = 0;
    private static LocalDateTime lastGameTimestamp = LocalDateTime.MIN;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        initializeLastGameTimestamp();
        start(System.in, System.out, args);
    }

    // Initialize last game timestamp from the file or set to current time if the file doesn't exist
    private static void initializeLastGameTimestamp() {
        try {
            File file = new File(TIMESTAMP_FILE);
            if (file.exists()) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String timestampString = reader.readLine();
                if (timestampString != null) {
                    lastGameTimestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(timestampString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
                    reader.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void saveLastGameTimestamp() {
        try {
            File file = new File(TIMESTAMP_FILE);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            writer.write(lastGameTimestamp.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void start(InputStream in, PrintStream out, String[] args) throws IOException {
        initializeLastGameTimestamp();
        String dictionaryFileName = "testdictionary.txt";
        if (null != args && args.length > 0) {
            dictionaryFileName = args[0];
        }

        List<String> wordList = getWordList(dictionaryFileName);
        start(in, out, wordList);
    }

    public static void start(InputStream in, PrintStream out, List<String> wordList) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);

        while (true) {
            if (!canPlayGame()) {
                break;
            }

            if (gamesPlayedToday >= MAX_DAILY_GAMES) {
                out.println("You have reached the maximum number of games for today.");
                break;
            }

            GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard(wordList);
            gameBoard.startGame();

            out.println("Games played today: " + gamesPlayedToday); // Moved inside the game loop

            boolean result = playOneGame(out, MAX_TRIES, gameBoard, scanner);
            if (result) {
                out.println("Congratulations, you won!");
            } else {
                out.println("Sorry, you lost!");
            }

            out.println("Play again? (Y/N)");

            if (!"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine().trim())) {
                break;
            }

            gamesPlayedToday++;
        }

        out.println("See you next time!");

        scanner.close();
    }

    private static boolean canPlayGame() {
        LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        long hoursBetween = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(lastGameTimestamp, currentTime);

        if (hoursBetween >= 24) {
            lastGameTimestamp = currentTime;
            saveLastGameTimestamp();
            gamesPlayedToday = 0; // Reset games played for a new day
        } else if (gamesPlayedToday >= MAX_DAILY_GAMES) {
            System.out.println("You have reached the maximum number of games for today.");
            return false;
        } else if (hoursBetween < 24) {
            System.out.println("You must wait for 24 hours before starting a new game.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    private static List<String> getWordList(String dictionaryFileName) throws IOException {
        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (InputStream inputStream = Commandle.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(dictionaryFileName);
             InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                wordList.add(line.trim().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        return wordList;
    }


    private static String getNextValidGuess(Scanner scanner, Set<String> guesses, GameBoard gameBoard) {
        String guess = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

        if (guess.length() != 5) {
            System.err.print("Please enter a word of 5 letters: ");
        } else if (guesses.contains(guess)) {
            System.err.print("Please enter a new word: ");
        } else if (!gameBoard.containsWord(guess)) {
            System.err.print("Please enter a valid word: ");
        } else {
            guesses.add(guess);
            return guess;
        }
        return getNextValidGuess(scanner, guesses, gameBoard);
    }

    private static boolean playOneGame(PrintStream out, int rounds, GameBoard gameBoard, Scanner scanner) {
        if (gamesPlayedToday >= MAX_DAILY_GAMES) {
            out.println("You have reached the maximum number of games for today.");
            return false;
        }

        Set<String> guesses = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
            out.print("Please enter your guess: ");
            String guess = getNextValidGuess(scanner, guesses, gameBoard);

            GameBoard.Status[] result = gameBoard.isInTarget(guess.toLowerCase().toCharArray());
            String hint = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                switch (result[j]) {
                    case correct -> hint += guess.charAt(j);
                    case wrong -> hint += "#";
                    case partial -> hint += "?";
                }
            }
            int round = i + 1;
            out.println(round + ": " + guess + "  " + round + ": " + hint);
            if (gameBoard.hasWon(result)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think the issue is in the canPlayGame logic and it's not seeing referencing this properly once a game has been played. Java isn't my main language so I'm struggling a bit to understand why this isn't working.

```
 private static boolean canPlayGame() {
        LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        long hoursBetween = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(lastGameTimestamp, currentTime);

        if (hoursBetween >= 24) {
            lastGameTimestamp = currentTime;
            saveLastGameTimestamp();
            gamesPlayedToday = 0; // Reset games played for a new day
        } else if (gamesPlayedToday >= MAX_DAILY_GAMES) {
            System.out.println("You have reached the maximum number of games for today.");
            return false;
        } else if (hoursBetween < 24) {
            System.out.println("You must wait for 24 hours before starting a new game.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It's a lot of code to read, but at first sight you're just reading the first timestamp you find in the file and not the last one.

Comment: The `else if (hoursBetween < 24)` in your `canPlayGame()` is most likely the issue. Since this will return `false` after one round, even if there are still games to play for this day. You'll probably have to think about if you want to only allow the amount of games for this day in one session, or you have to also store the number of games played today like you do the timestamp.

Comment: _"... it only let me play 1 game instead of 10. ..."_, if I run the code it just _recursively_ calls _getNextValidGuess_.